# Saving Multiple NFC Tags - Issue modifying tutorial to save multiple NDef Records

Tags: android, nfc

I'm following a tutorial which allows users to save data to NFC tags. I'm attempting to modify the tutorial source code to include a second EditText field and save a second tag however I can only save the second NDef record if I comment out the following line:

// write(message.getText().toString(),mytag);

I need to be able to write both tags:

```
write(message.getText().toString(),mytag);
```

and

```
write(message.getText().toString(),mytag2);
```

...but I need help concatenating them together.

There is an example showing how to add multiple tags here:

https://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/source/browse/nfc-eclipse-plugin/src/android/nfc16/NdefMessage.java

but I need help formatting my current source to reflect this method. (Every time I try I end up with additional problems in my log or force close issues.)

Thanks in advance!

JAVA:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.FormatException;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


@SuppressLint({ "ParserError", "ParserError" })
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    NfcAdapter adapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    IntentFilter writeTagFilters[];
    boolean writeMode;
    Tag mytag;
    Tag mytag2;
    Context ctx;
    Context ctx2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ctx=this;
        Button btnWrite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final TextView message = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);

        ctx2=this;
        final TextView message2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit_message2);


        btnWrite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if(mytag==null){
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.error_detected), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

                    if(mytag2==null){
                        Toast.makeText(ctx2, ctx2.getString(R.string.error_detected), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                        }
                    }else{
                        // write(message.getText().toString(),mytag);
                        write(message.getText().toString(),mytag2);
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.ok_writing), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                        Toast.makeText(ctx2, ctx2.getString(R.string.ok_writing), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.error_writing), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    Toast.makeText(ctx2, ctx2.getString(R.string.error_writing), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FormatException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.error_writing) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    Toast.makeText(ctx2, ctx2.getString(R.string.error_writing) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };

    }



    private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {

        NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text) };
        NdefMessage  message = new NdefMessage(records);
        // Get an instance of Ndef for the tag.
        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);


        // SUGGESTED IMPLEMENTATION
        //  mRecords = new NdefRecord[1 + records.length];
           // mRecords[0] = record;
           // System.arraycopy(records, 0, mRecords, 1, records.length);





        // Enable I/O
        ndef.connect();
        // Write the message
        ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);

        // Close the connection
        ndef.close();
    }



    private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String lang       = "en";
        byte[] textBytes  = text.getBytes();
        byte[] langBytes  = lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
        int    langLength = langBytes.length;
        int    textLength = textBytes.length;
        byte[] payload    = new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

        // set status byte (see NDEF spec for actual bits)
        payload[0] = (byte) langLength;

        // copy langbytes and textbytes into payload
        System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1,              langLength);
        System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1 + langLength, textLength);

        NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,  NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT,  new byte[0], payload);

        return recordNFC;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            mytag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);   
            mytag2 = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);   
            Toast.makeText(this, this.getString(R.string.ok_detection) + mytag.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        WriteModeOff();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        WriteModeOn();
    }

    private void WriteModeOn(){
        writeMode = true;
        adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);
    }

    private void WriteModeOff(){
        writeMode = false;
        adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }


}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please Enter Your Password: ">
    </TextView>



         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:hint="SSID" />



     <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:hint="WiFi Password" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Write!!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Tutorial Source Code (showing implementation of the source above which only saves one NDef record - I've modified it to save two NDef records)

http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/31/write-hello-world-into-a-nfc-tag-with-a/

Comment: mytag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);    
            Toast.makeText(this,   this.getString(R.string.ok_detection) + mytag.toString(),   Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
  

does the Toast show something coming from the intent?

Comment: Nope - not toast appears when clicking the Write button (the only toast that appears is when you hold the NFC tag close to the device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out this one line:

```
write(message.getText().toString(),mytag);
```

And I think it will work.

The problem I believe is that the `write()` method is designed to only write to one tag, and by the time the second write() method is called, the tag is still locked by the first write() method. If I were you, I'd try adding a second field inside the definition of the write() definition, or if that's not possible, I'd try concatenating the text of the two fields together with a marker in the middle of the two.

Also to make this proper code, I'd do the nfc part inside its own thread using AsyncTask to make sure it doesn't block the UI thread. I understand why the guy writing the tutorial didn't do that, that would have made his tutorial much more complicated than he wanted to, but doing nfc is something you should be keeping out of the UI thread.

**Regarding your second question:**

This might do it:

```
private void write(String text, String text2, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {

    NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text), createRecord(text2) };
    NdefMessage  message = new NdefMessage(records);
    // Get an instance of Ndef for the tag.
    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);

    // Enable I/O
    ndef.connect();
    // Write the message
    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);

    // Close the connection
    ndef.close();
}
```

and of course, this means you'll have to call it this way (since it now has one more argument):

```
write(message.getText().toString(), message2.getText().toString(), mytag2);
```

Comment: I commented out write(message.getText().toString(),mytag2); and the app stops force closing (thank you) but I'd like to know the proper way to the proper method of adding a second field in the write() definition! (Thanks in advance! - John)

Comment: write(message.getText().toString(),mytag, mytag2); 

does not seem to work

Comment: Inside your definition of onNewIntent(Intent intent), you have it hardcoded to using mytag. That might have been the issue.

Comment: Commenting out the line suggested allows the second record to save however Im having serious trouble implementing the suggested example into my source code.

Comment: Your assistance is greatly appreciated... (and invaluable!)

Comment: I tried just now (thanks for your help!) and I'm getting an error stating "text 2 cannot be resolved to a variable" and the application force closes

Comment: [also - replacing text2 with either of my variables does not resolve the issue]

Comment: Did you see my response of one hour ago in the main body of my answer? You shouldn't be getting that error message if you changed the signature of your method definition as such: private void write(String text, String text2, Tag tag) etc.

Comment: You my friend... are a godsend!! (Thank you so much!!! Your response(s) resolved all my issues!!!)